# ASP.NET app hosted inside SharePoint – How to selectively disable aspx pages

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

We are creating an ASP.NET application that will be hosted in the layouts directory of the company’s SharePoint farm. The application is configurable so that depending on which site collection the application is deployed to, it will appear differently based on some SharePoint lists.

The problem we’ve run into is some sites will need certain pages and others will not. It may be a security risk if someone where to go poking around and happen across those pages in an out of context for the site collection.

The two possibilities we have considered are, just deleting the aspx pages manually after deploy, or on page load, see if a page is valid and if not, thrown an exception or redirect.

Is there a better way of going about this? Is there potentially a ‘SharePoint’ way of doing this?

Comment: Sounds like a job for SPSecurityContext

Answer (score 1):

I would add a specific feature per targeted SPWeb / SPSite, automatically activated (or manually depending on your deployment process) and within your ~Site/_layouts/xyz.aspx you can if the current SPSite or current SPWeb has this specific feature activated. If so, you allow access otherwsise you redirect with SPUtility.TransferToErrorPage("Access Denied, bla bla bla");

That will allow you to secure your aspx to only the specific area where the associated feature is enabled (you can have a generic feature as well) and prevent access outside of any valid / relevant context.